# Is there any tool to migrate data from MySQL (or mongodb) to Aerospike?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, aerospike

I would like to migrate data from MySQL (or mongodb) to Aerospike, anyone knows if exists any tool to do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aerospike provides something like a csv loader.

https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-loader

So you can play around with mysqldump data , process the dumped file to create a csv as per the accepted format of aerospike-loader and then load the data into aerospike.

Answer (score -1):

There is a simple python script I have developed. I have been using it for my projects since we are moving all our databases from MySQL to MongoDB. It migrates around 1 Lakh rows in a minute. [Migrate MySQL to MongoDB](https://github.com/alwaysanirudh/Migrate-MySQL-to-MongoDB)

Comment: Question is about Mysql/Mongo to Aerospike, not Mysql to Mongodb